# Append table name on GSON

Tags: json, gson

I created a restful service witch generates JSON with the GSON api, but i need table name in front of the JSON structure, and i can't show this, let me show the codes

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import model.AccessManager;
import dto.Usuarios;

@Path("/UsuariosService")
public class UsuariosService
{
    @GET
    @Path("/usuarios")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String usuarios()
    {
        String usuarios = null;
        ArrayList<Usuarios> usuariosList = new ArrayList<Usuarios>();
        try
        {
            usuariosList = new AccessManager().getUsuarios();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            usuarios = gson.toJson(usuariosList);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return usuarios;
    }
}
```

The return I need is:

```
{
 "usuarios" : [
  {"usr_id":1,"usr_login":"teste@gmail.com","usr_pwd":"123456"},
  {"usr_id":2,"usr_login":"teste@teste.com.br","usr_pwd":"123456"}
 ]
}
```

But the return I get is:

```
[
  {"usr_id":1,"usr_login":"teste@gmail.com","usr_pwd":"123456"},
  {"usr_id":2,"usr_login":"teste@teste.com.br","usr_pwd":"123456"}
]
```

i.e. without the table's name, but that name is needed in my SAPUI5 Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stops you from just adding that as `String`

```
"{\"usuarios\" :" + gson.toJson(usuariosList) + "}"
```

Although you need to escape **"**

Otherwise you have to introduce a different return object

```
class ReturnObject {
   List<Usuarios> usuarios;       
   public ReturnObject(List<Usuarios> usuarios) {
       this.usuarios = usuarios;
   }
}
```

And use that

```
gson.toJson(new ReturnObject(usuariosList));
```